# Angular2 Web Worker - view not updated

Tags: angular, typescript, web-worker

I have created a component which implement Worker() object to generate large amount of random numbers. I listen to `Worker() onmessage` event that is fired after single random number is generated. `Onmessage` event handler change the component model (checked in console) but the view is not updated.

Tried with `NgZone`, `ChangeDetectionRef` but no luck. I would appreciate the help because I`m stuck in this for days.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, NgZone, Input,ChangeDetectorRef }from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<h1>Counter :{{counter}}</h1>`,  
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

    private counter: number = 0;  

    constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef){}

    private _webWorker: Worker;

    ngOnInit(){ 

        var blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([
          "onmessage = function (val) { for (var x = 0; x < val.data; x++) { postMessage( Math.random() ) } };"                             
        ], { type: 'application/javascript' }));

        this._webWorker = new Worker(blobURL); 
        this._webWorker.addEventListener('message', (val) => {
            console.log("Returned form webworker..." + val.data);
            this.counter = val.data;
            this.cd.markForCheck(); //also not working with NgZone.run()
        });

        this._webWorker.postMessage(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems it works well. Check this https://plnkr.co/edit/Ytz9RSXSQDLl96uRZSlg?p=preview

Comment: @yurzi - it shows only the last generated number nothing in between.

Comment: Have you tried to use delay for your postMessage? Here is no problem with change detection

Comment: @yurzi - Yes I have. No change. Does change detection happen on each number generated ? For me that is not the case. In plunker also the same only the last number is shown no change detection meanwhile.

Comment: Put debugger after this.counter = val.data; and observe

Comment: See this example https://plnkr.co/edit/nnIus1jiijUYgsZv6lYx?p=preview

Comment: I used setTimeout in the wrong place. It`s a workaround but works. Thank you very much @yurzi.